# Entity Framework mapping to table

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am trying to define a mapping to another table using the following method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Ansprechpartner>().Map(x => x.ToTable("Ansprechpartnerdaten"));
```

I created two DbContexts: One default context containing entities which should not be modified (private setter)

and another EditContext which should be used when editing.

I get the following error Message (sorry - in German):

> EditContextTest.TestMethod1-Testmethode hat eine Ausnahme ausgelöst:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Die Entitätstypen 'Ansprechpartner'
>   und 'AnsprechpartnerEdit' können die Tabelle 'Ansprechpartner' nicht
>   gemeinsam verwenden, weil sie sich nicht in derselben Typhierarchie
>   befinden und nicht über eine gültige 1:1-Fremdschlüsselbeziehung mit
>   übereinstimmenden Primärschlüsseln verfügen.

Error message says that Entity Framework is trying to map Ansprechpartner and AnsprechpartnerEdit to table Ansprechpartner.

So I am trying to map:

```
Model               | Table
--------------------+---------------------
Ansprechpartner     | Ansprechpartnerdaten
AnsprechpartnerEdit | Ansprechpartner
```

which doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one option is to rename the Model class `Ansprechpartner` to another name.
I tested `AnsprechpartnerXX`. I don't want to rename the class, I cannot come up with a better / different name. You know naming things is one of the hard problems in CS.

Another solution is to Ignore all Ansprechpartner related things in the mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Ignore<Ansprechpartner>();
    modelBuilder.Ignore<AktivitätenAnsprechpartner>();
    modelBuilder.Ignore<AnsprechpartnerInteressen>();
    modelBuilder.Ignore<VerkaufschancenAnsprechpartner>();
    modelBuilder.Ignore<LeadsAnsprechpartner>();
```

I am doing that for now. I don't need this classes for now and I plan to implement a EditModel for them aswell anyway.

I still hope there are other solutions.